# Shortcut key to focus the address bar in Firefox for Android

Tags: firefox-for-android, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using a Bluetooth keyboard with my Android tablet with Firefox (57+). I tried Ctrl+L, Alt+D to focus the address bar, but it does not work.

Is there a shortcut (not using "F" Keys) for focusing the address bar? Or addon?

Comment: Have you tried [Shortkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/shortkeys-custom-shortcuts/)?

Comment: @aviyoop Does not work with android firefox :/